# How to sort the relations returned using get work items API?

Tags: javascript, tfs, azure-devops, tfs-workitem, workitem

I am writing a TFS extension in javascript where I am using the 'GetWorkItem' function within 'TFS/WorkItemTracking/RestClient' library.

```
 wiRestClient.getWorkItem(<workItemID>, null, null, Contracts.WorkItemExpand.All)
            .then(function success(workItem) {
                console.log(workItem); 
 });
```

the output generated by the code above is as below:
[image: Output]

This PBI has about 40 tasks within it and they are fetched in random order by the API.

Is there a way that these relations are fetched in the order of their Id?

I process the relations returned in the result, fetch the Id from a forward relation, get the workItemId
and add it to an array.

Now, this array has information about all the child workitems of the parent PBI.
I tried to sort this array based on System.Id in the fields property.
This is the function I use to sort the data:

```
 childWorkItems.sort(function(a,b) {
     return a["System.Id"] > b.["System.Id"]
 });
 console.log(childWorkItems);
```

This doesn't seem to work. The array is still in random order.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could Accept it as an Answer , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved by changing the sort function to

```
 childWorkItems.sort(function(a,b) {
      return a["System.Id"] - b.["System.Id"]
 });
 console.log(childWorkItems);
```